# is dnode supported by heroku?

Tags: heroku, dnode

When I try to apply this simple node app at heroku, I got error:

```
no port or path provided
```

Here is the app:

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});

var dnode = require('dnode');
var server = dnode({
    zing : function (n, cb) { cb(n * 100) }
});
server.listen(app);
```

and here is the browser index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/dnode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            DNode.connect(function (remote) {
                remote.zing(66, function (n) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = n;
                });
            });

        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

n = <span id="result">?</span>

</body>
</html>
```

then, heroku logs:

```
2013-05-28T18:38:55.246545+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw new Error('no port or path provided');
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at D.dnode.listen (/app/node_modules/dnode/index.js:119:15)
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:20:8)
2013-05-28T18:38:55.246124+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/dnode/index.js:119
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:901:3
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2013-05-28T18:38:55.246854+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: no port or path provided
2013-05-28T18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2013-05-28T
18:38:55.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2013-05-28T18:38:56.512438+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-05-28T18:38:56.530982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-05-28T18:39:04.462914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-05-28T18:39:04.462914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
```

Is there something I am missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the old version api (<1). The new version is just a stream. Check the current readme for how to [pipe everything together with the new api](https://github.com/substack/dnode#dnode-in-the-browser).

Comment: I tried that, but, I couldn't install shoe on heroku, kindly see answers I got here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692315/failed-to-rebuild-dependencies-with-npm it would work if I could use it with express ..

Comment: So, can't I use it in browser without using shoe? just express?